# how to represent functional language debug information in llvm source level debug information?

Tags: debugging, f#, functional-programming, llvm

I am developing a llvm frontend for a language based on F#, a functional language. Well, the functional language matches the concept of value, not variable. F# also support variable by so called "mutable value", and I can model it as a %llvm.dbg.declare() to track the value. but I don't know how to track the value. a value isn't created by alloca, it is just a value, will not change. And the examples are all telling implementation on imperative language such as C, which doesn't have this immutable value concept. Anyone has some suggestion or hint on debug information for functional style language?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe compile some C++ with `const` using `llvm-gcc -g -O0` and see what it produces?

Comment: @EliBendersky F# is a statically typed language. "values" refer to immutable variables in F#.

Answer (score 0):

For SSA values you use `@llvm.dbg.value()` instead of `@llvm.dbg.declare`. First you have to define the metadata for the local value just as you would for `@llvm.dbg.declare`, below I assume it is defined as `!4`. The LLVM IR would look like

```
%x = ...
call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata !{ i32 %x }, i64 0, metadata !4)
```

I got this information from http://nondot.org/sabre/LLVMNotes/DebugInfoVariableInfo.txt which describes how mem2reg transforms the debugging information. It's possible this is out of date with respect to current LLVM practices so you could write some IR with `alloca`s and `@llvm.dbg.declare`, then run the mem2reg pass to see how the debugging information changes when it is converted to SSA.